# Facebook Login Auth using HTTP on mobile with no browser

Tags: facebook, http, java-me, authentication

I'm trying to login to Facebook using a HTTP connection on mobile using these URLs:

```
String URL1= "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=128991357211271&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=offline_access&display=touch&response_type=token";
String URL2="http://m.facebook.com/login.php?app_id=128991357211271&cancel=httpsu00253Au00252Fu00252Fwww.facebook.comu00252Fconnectu00252Flogin_success.htmlu00253Ferror_reasonu00253Duser_deniedu002526erroru00253Daccess_deniedu002526error_descriptionu00253DTheu00252Buseru00252Bdeniedu00252Byouru00252Brequest.&fbconnect=1&next=httpsu00253Au00252Fu00252Fwww.facebook.comu00252Fdialogu00252Fpermissions.requestu00253F_pathu00253Dpermissions.requestu002526app_idu00253D128991357211271u002526redirect_uriu00253Dhttpsu0025253Au0025252Fu0025252Fwww.facebook.comu0025252Fconnectu0025252Flogin_success.htmlu002526displayu00253Dwapu002526response_typeu00253Dtokenu002526permsu00253Doffline_accessu002526fbconnectu00253D1u002526from_loginu00253D1u002526client_idu00253D128991357211271&rcount=1&_rdr";
String URL3="https://m.facebook.com/login.php?m=m&amp;next=http0X1.705B00P-767%2Fm.facebook.comttpsu00253Au00252Fu00252Fwww.facebook.comu00252Fdialogu00252Fpermissions.requestu00253F_pathu00253Dpermissions.requestu002526app_idu00253D128991357211271u002526redirect_uriu00253Dhttpsu0025253Au0025252Fu0025252Fwww.facebook.comu0025252Fconnectu0025252Flogin_success.htmlu002526displayu00253Dwapu002526response_typeu00253Dtokenu002526permsu00253Doffline_accessu002526fbconnectu00253D1u002526from_loginu00253D1u002526client_idu00253D128991357211271&amp;refsrc=http0X1.BDEA81P-744%2Fm.facebook.com2476350215gin.php&amp;refid=9";
String param3="email=myemail&pass=mypass";
String URL4="http://m.facebook.com/download.php?refsrc=http0X1.5C08C1P-688%2Fm.facebook.com1170gin.php&amp;m_sess=R8Vnc-b9WcLHqr&amp;_rdr&amp;manual_redirect=1";
```

First, I try to access `URL1`, and then in the result there is a link to `URL2`
which I then access, and so on...

When I try to access `URL3` and post my email and pass using HTTP post, `URL4` is in the result. However, when I try to access `URL4`, the result is the same (there is a link to `URL4` again).

When I try to open `URL4` in a web browser, it says that I have to install Facebook for mobile.

Why does it always ask to install Facebook for mobile? Or is there a better way of how to login to Facebook using an HTTP connection only?

Comment: Why this may be theoretically possible, what you trying to do is strictly prohibited by [TOS](http://www.facebook.com/legal/terms)

Answer (score 3):

Refer to *[Using Facebook Connect on Mobile (J2ME)](http://facebookgarage.pbworks.com/w/page/27176234/Using%20Facebook%20Connect%20on%20Mobile%20%28J2ME%29)* and *[Facebook API ME 1.0: Tutorial](http://j2megroup.blogspot.in/2011/06/facebook-api-me-10-tutorial.html)*.

For code samples for BlackBerry and Android, see *[Facebook API ME](http://kenai.com/projects/facebookapime/downloads)*. I hope you will get the idea on how to use Facebook API in [Java ME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition).